# How to access the columns of a row returned by a query in database for protractor?

Tags: database, angular, testing, protractor

I am getting a complete row by the query I am using. I want to access all the columns and compare with my data. Is there any function like `result.get(0)` in protractor so that I can compare the column values, like I do in selenium

Comment: can u paste the our put row here?

Comment: And what is the query you are using? Stackoverflow requires you to provide accurate/reproducible examples and detailed errors/issues.